# Skip over empty cells while using if condition for Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in my DataFrame which contains values 1, 0, and backorder. I used the strip() method to remove the backorder values in order to get this code to work, but now it won't run with empty cells. Is there a way to just skip over these empty boxes since i don't want them or their surrounding columns to be affected.

My code is attempting to make a new column using the 1s and 0s.

```
final_dataframe = final_dataframe.applymap(lambda df_value: str(df_value).rstrip('backorder'))
#Removes "backorder" from In stock? column (temporarily)

final_dataframe['In stock?'] = final_dataframe['In stock?'].astype(int)
conditions = [
    (final_dataframe['In stock?'] == 1 & [final_dataframe['qty_total'] < 1]),
    (final_dataframe['In stock?'] == 0 & [final_dataframe['qty_total'] >= 1])
]
t_or_f = ['True', 'False']
final_dataframe['Unlist This']
print(final_dataframe)
```

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example (just a few rows) of your dataset and the desired output ?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow!  please review guidelines in posting a reproducible example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

With no of example data its difficult to answer. What if you removed the rows that have the "backorder" values. `fdf` will be `final_dataframe`. So if is it not equal it is kept.

```
fdf = fdf[fdf['backorder']!='backorder']
```

If you like the answer check it as accepted. If it does not provide an example.